# Simultaneous inserts in CoreData in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Suppose if i have thousand  record coming from the web service API and if i want to add those record in core data in privateContext. How can i do it simultaneous and not linearly.

Can i apply something like `dispatch_apply` and run

```
let entity:NSEntityDescription =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName,
            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)!
let managedObject:NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
```

simultaneously ?

Comment: You can use dispatch_async, performBlock (in managedContext). But don't save the context every time, once you finished all insert operations do the save context.

Comment: My question is bit different .... i want to do simultaneous insert. for example i want to insert 100 record in parallel in 10 different queue.

Comment: From this article (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html), it seems you would need a different private queue context for each queue.  If you get it to work, I wonder whether the underlying database will allow parallel updates or serialize them itself.

Comment: @PhillipMills Yep that's what i am wondering. I want to know if is there any advantage of doing this optimizations or not

Comment: You may have to test it to find out or else investigate how SQLite (if that's your store type) responds to threading.  I don't imagine any guarantees can be made at the CoreData level because different storage will act differently.  (I can even imagine one database product acting differently depending on the schema.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
func persistAsyncInContext<T:AnyObject>(parentContext:NSManagedObjectContext , objetcsFromJSON:[T] , completion:()->Void){

    let workQ = dispatch_queue_create(nil, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
    let workGroup = dispatch_group_create()

    for objectFromJSON in objetcsFromJSON{

        dispatch_group_enter(workGroup)
        let workerChildMoc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        workerChildMoc.parentContext = parentContext
        workerChildMoc.performBlock{

            let managedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("entityName", inManagedObjectContext: workerChildMoc)
            //if objectFromJSON is also an array then loop it and move the line above that creates new object into the loop.

            do
            {
                try workerChildMoc.save()
            }
            catch
            {
                //Handle error
            }
            defer{
                dispatch_group_leave(workGroup)
            }
        }
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(workGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        do{
            try parentContext.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            //Handle error
        }
        //End of persist
        completion()
    }
}
```

This creates each object in a child context and saves them , BUT take into consider that doing this for a lot of objects is not efficient , You may want to create a 2D array of JSON objects (ex. if you have 1000 objects then chunk them to 10 arrays of 100 objects and parse the 10 arrays async on 10 child contexts).

Hope it helps.